# The phrase "etwas nervös" in the sentence "Ich bin nur etwas nervös"

Tags: meaning

> Ich bin nur **etwas nervös**.

This sentence literally translates into "I'm just something nervous", correct? So does it basically mean "I'm just a little nervous"?

How does it compare with the version that omits the word "etwas"?

> Ich bin nur **nervös**.

Comment: Did you use a dictionary? "something" is only one of many translations for "etwas", and clearly not the right one in your example sentence. https://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&lp=frde&search=etwas&searchLoc=0&relink=on&spellToler=standard&cmpType=relaxed

Comment: *somewhat nervous* would have been a better choice than *something..*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about both the translation and the meaning of *etwas* in this sentence. You could replace *etwas* with *ein bisschen* and the meaning would stay the same.

> Ich bin nur ein bisschen nervös.

You can do the same in many other cases, such as

> *Sie nahm etwas Salz.* = Sie nahm ein bisschen Salz.
>
> *Ich brauche etwas Geld.* = Ich brauche ein bisschen Geld.

As to how it compares to the sentence without the *etwas*.. The same as in English!

> Ich bin nur etwas nervös. = I'm just a bit nervous.
>
> Ich bin nur nervös. = I'm just nervous.

The first one sounds a bit milder than the second one.

Comment: Well, and the two sentences (with and without "etwas") can have different use cases. E.g.: "Are you nervous?" "Well, yes. But I am just a bit nervous" versus "Are you fine? You don't look too well." "Yes, I'm fine. I'm just nervous. That's it." Of course, the latter one would be fine with "just a bit", too.